# Docker mount order out of sequence and not letting me mount my directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, bind, docker-volume, rancheros

My docker-compose.yml is as following

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     container_name: mysql-wordpress
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     ports:
       - "3300:3306"
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     container_name: wordpress
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
     ports:
       - "80:80"
       - "443:443"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress

   phpmyadmin:
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      container_name: phpmyadmin
      depends_on:
         - db
      restart: always
      ports:
         - "8080:80"
      environment:
        - PMA_ARBITRARY=1

volumes:
    db_data:
```

When I start `docker-compose up -d`

the wp-content directory does not have the same content of host inside the container wp-content directory.

When I do `docker inspect WordPress`:

```
"Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/rootfs/home/rancher/projects/tabletop/uploads.ini",
            "Destination": "/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        },
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/rootfs/home/rancher/projects/tabletop/wp-content",
            "Destination": "/var/www/html/wp-content",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        },
        {
            "Type": "volume",
            "Name": "d0a4f5ad342db0db782b41dd676aa0e58a324b5e7db1e56086bca5550a9ffdc3",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/d0a4f5ad342db0db782b41dd676aa0e58a324b5e7db1e56086bca5550a9ffdc3/_data",
            "Destination": "/var/www/html",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        }
```

It seems the third mount might have overridden my bind mount. But I don't know where it is coming from. How can I have my wp-content mount after it?

Update:
This problem occurs only on rancherOS , on coreOS and linux Mint its working fine

Comment: Try adding `- wp-html:/var/www/html` as the first named volume mapping and see if that helps? define the `wp-html` volume if needed

Comment: @TarunLalwani tried it didn't worked still it adds the named valued in the end although I have defined it fist.

Comment: I really dont know anything but i noticed in docker-compose you have container name "wordpress" but you use container name "WordPress" for inspection.  Are container names case sensitive - in which case you are looking at the wrong container.  If they are insensitive and you sure they are the same cluld you edit the question to remove a source od confusion.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you know that you can create two kind of volumes (let's ignore for this explanation tmpfs):

- bind-type volume
- volume-type volume

  - named volumes.
  - unnamed volumes.

When you create a bind-type, it's done an association between two directories or files.

**When you create a volume-type, internally, it's done also a bind** between /var/lib/docker/volumes//_data and destination.
 can be a string given by you (named volume) or a string like yours: d0a4f5ad342db0db782b... (unnamed volume)

> So, you've created two bind-volumes from your local directory in host
>   ./wp-contend furthermore a bind volume for uploads.ini file.
>   Everything is ok.

The point is that you've inherit an unnamed volume from `image: wordpress:latest`.

If you had Dockerfile which was used to generate wordpress:latest, you would see a line like:

`VOLUME [/var/www/html]`

So, it's generated an unnamed volume in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/d0a4f5ad342db0db782b41dd676aa0e58a324b5e7db1e56086bca5550a9ffdc3/_data`
That is done to avoid lose all generated  information if container exits. Is a way to keep consistency of the data.
So, if originally you had a single file `your_file.txt` in your `./wp-content`, after `wordpress` starts, **wordpress** creates in `wp-content` the following dirs/files if don't exist:
 - index.php
 - plugins/
 - themes/
You should have the same information in your ./wp-content that you had before `docker-compose -d up` plus these generated-by-wordpress file and dirs, **because you're mounting a bind volume in a subfolder over an already-mounted volume from wordpress image.**

Comment: thanks for the detail explanation , so is there any way I can mount bind volume over the un-named volume ?

Comment: You could overwrite volume if you mounted `/var/www/html`, but if you mount another folder inside it, the original `VOLUME [/var/www/html]` persists.